# How to use find quietly?

Tags: find

I want to search for all occurences of `<searchterm>` on my machine. Now when I perform a search like this

```
find / <searchterm>
```

I can see all the paths the search is running through. How can I limit the results to my searchterm?

**Abstract example**

I have a folder, let's call it `my-own-folder`. Now when I want to know if there are any other folders with the same name and run a search for

```
find / my-own-folder
```

the output shows a couple of hundred lines like this

```
/var/www/my-own-folder/index.php
/var/www/my-own-folder/lib/1.php
/var/www/my-own-folder/templates/2.php
/var/www/my-own-folder/log/3.log
```

followed by another thousands of lines (~380k lines) that contain `/usr`, `/lib`, `/proc`, `/var` and so on, examples:

```
/etc/gshadow
/etc/fonts
/dev/ram7
/media/user
/run/udev/watch
/bin/gzexe
/vmlinuz
/lost+found
```

And the lines don't contain `my-own-folder`. I highly doubt, that they're all connected to that folder. So why are they outputted?

**Precise example**

I want to [apply a patch for openldap](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openldap/+bug/1392018) but don't know where I can find the folder in order to run the patch. So when I search

```
find / openldap
find / slapd
```

it seems to output all locations where the search is performed, and not only the occurences of `openldap` or `slapd`.

## Update

My fault was not to use `-name` in my search like this

```
find / -name "<searchterm>"
```

Comment: What are you searching for?

Comment: Any arbitrary content

Comment: check my answer

Comment: What's your goal ? you just wanna know if `find` has found something ?

Comment: @Serg I precised my question

Comment: Can you give any examples of the lines it outputs that it shouldn't?  Your sample output seems to only show lines that definitely *do* contain the search term.

Comment: @thomasrutter Have added unwanted examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit the amount of output you can use either `head` or `tail` to read either first or last x number of terms. For example,

```
$ find . -iname "*test*" | head -n 10
find: `./.cache/dconf'./xterm-297/tektests
./xterm-297/tektests/imtesth.tek
./xterm-297/tektests/fotest.tek
./xterm-297/tektests/aitest.tek
./xterm-297/tektests/imtest.tek
./xterm-297/testxmc.c
./xterm-297/Tests
./xterm-297/vttests
./test.c
: Permission denied./file2.test
```

You can also use `less` to view the output conveniently with page-up / down buttons.

`find / -type d -name "foldername" | less`

You can also use `! -path` to tell find to ignore some specific folder

`find . ! -path /somedirectory/anotherdirectory -iname "searchterm"`

of use `grep -v termyoudontwant`. -v flag allows to ignore stuff what you don't want to see in the output

`find . -name "searchterm" | grep -v idontwantthatstuff` `

Find allows specifying what type do you want to search for. If you want to search for folders, type is d. To search for all folders on the system named `test`, run this:

`find / -type d -name "test"`

Here's a concrete example to search for exact directory on my system:

```
$ sudo find / -type d -name "bin"                                              
/home/xieerqi/bin
/usr/lib/initramfs-tools/bin
/usr/lib/klibc/bin
/usr/lib/pm-utils/bin
/usr/lib/2013.com.canonical.certification:checkbox/bin
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin
/usr/lib/ure/bin
/usr/lib/2013.com.canonical.certification:plainbox-resources/bin
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/plainbox/impl/providers/stubbox/bin
/usr/lib/guile-2.0/bin
/usr/share/qt4/bin
/usr/share/libreoffice/bin
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-30/tools/testing/selftests/rcutorture/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
```

If I want to ignore the `/usr/` entries, I run this:

```
$ sudo find /   -type d -name "bin" | grep -v '\/usr\/*'                       
/home/xieerqi/bin
/bin
```

To ignore the directories /usr, /lib, /proc, /var , change grep like this

`grep -v '\/usr\/*\|\/lib\/*\|\/proc\/*\|\/var\/*'`

Comment: Even I didn't downvote, but pleas how could you see the output if you redirect both output and error?  2>&1  I think you shouldn't redirect the output also! I think your way of answering make some confusion. Please edit your answer and just answer the needed

Comment: Maythux, I've removed that part. Thought OP didn't want any output from the command and just wanted to check the exit status `$?`, but I guess I was wrong. I looked through OP's edit, so it's more clear now

Comment: @Serg Not really making me happy, I still get a lot of output unrelated to my searchterm...

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel see my edit. I've added searching for directories only and there's also `less` command to make viewing long output convenient

Comment: Didn't use `-name ""` (see my question update). I accepted this answer as it's most helpful for searching in general. Thanks!

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel Well that was easy , right ? :D Glad I could help !

Answer (score 8):

You can use [redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html):

```
find / <searchterm> 2>/dev/null
```

This redirect all errors to the [null device /dev/null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device).

for example:

```
 # find / -name StewieGriffin\*
/root: Permission denied
/home/peterg: Permission denied
/home/stewie/StewieGriffin-resume.doc
```

Would be converted to

```
# find / -name StewieGriffin\* 2>/dev/null
/home/stewie/StewieGriffin-resume.doc
```

Please take a more look on this [link](http://www.simplehelp.net/2011/04/03/how-to-use-the-find-command-in-linux/).

Comment: Still shows me hundrets of lines that don't seem to be related to my search (see added example in my question)

Comment: Didn't use `-name ""` (see my question update), thanks for your help!

Comment: This answer works, but why isn't there a simple option in `find`?  Linux is so dumb sometimes...

Comment: @YanKingYin agreed. I came here because I know of the stderr redirect, but wanted a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, **-name** is the flag to use as it is built in to **find**. As a more general purpose solution which will cover you when other apps don't have a tool to rationalise search results (apt-get for example) you can use grep.

```
find / <searchterm> | grep <searchterm>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a blankspace between `/` and `my-own-folder`. Set full path to the folder like this:

```
# find /var/www/my-own-folder
```

This will only output the content of `my-own-folder`.

Comment: Uh, I thought the first statement after `find` is the place to start the search from?

Comment: @gottliebNotschnabel technically, if you want to search just one particular folder, that's what you specify in the path. So if I want to search everything in `/home/myusername/bin` folder , I'd run `find /home/myusername/bin  -name "searchterm"` Like that. Telling find to search from / means searching the whole system, all the folders

Comment: Uh okay, misunderstanding: I'm not looking for content of that path, but for all occurences of `my-own-folder` on the system.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel so let me get this clear. You just wanna know all the occurrences of your *folder*. Only folder, no files, nothing else. Right ? What other things you *don't * want in the search ? I'm gonna update my answer in a second, please see

Comment: Basically, I want to find all occurences of `searchterm`, not only folders. I aedded a precise example to my question in order to specify

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel see my addditions to the answer